# Regarding Azure Framework

Tags: azure

Aure has released any dll/framework which can be used instead of using REST APIs?
instead of implementing rest APIs for Azure VM/Cloud service management ,is there any readymade dll/framework is relased?If yes,where can I find the details about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something similar to storage client library, unfortunately no such thing similar to that exists today for managing VMs. However there're a few options:

- You can use Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets
- You can use Windows Azure Command Line (CLI) Tools

Both of them can be downloaded from here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/. Furthermore, the source code for both of them is available on Github: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/.

Yet another alternative is to use `Azure Fluent Management Library` by Elastacloud guys. This is again open source and is available via [`NuGet`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Elastacloud.AzureManagement.Fluent/). More information about this library can be found here: http://fluentmanagement.elastacloud.com/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Gaurav...you are the most active expert in this site...Kudos to you..!